# Left join not producing correct result

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I want to return all people regardless of whether they have a sale on any given day. My initial response to solve this would be

```
SELECT 
    P.[Name], P.[id], 
    F.[DATE], F.[Figure], F.[id]
FROM
    Person P
LEFT JOIN 
    Figure F ON P.id = F.id
```

An example of the result for this is

```
 Name           id      DATE         Figure
--------------------------------------------
 Tom            1       2017-09-27   15
 Fred           2       2017-09-27   20
 Jane           3       2017-09-25   0
 Ben            4       2017-09-25   0
```

Now as soon as I limit the date to today's date, I get nothing.

```
SELECT 
    P.[Name], P.[id], 
    F.[DATE], F.[Figure], F.[id]
FROM
    Person P
LEFT JOIN 
    Figure F ON P.id = F.id
WHERE 
    F.Date = GETDATE()
```

I understand this is probably because there is no one with today's date attached to them but how do I still display all of the people even if they had nothing for today? I thought that a left join would accomplish this but it doesn't.

My desired results would be :

```
 Name           id      DATE         Figure
--------------------------------------------
 Tom            1       2017-10-02   0
 Fred           2       2017-10-02   0
 Jane           3       2017-10-02   0
 Ben            4       2017-10-02   0
```

There are no keys in the tables so I feel as though that might be why the left join isn't working as I expected but has anyone got any ideas how I can get the desired result?

Comment: do you have record for today's date ?

Comment: No, not that i can see. But is it possible to still display as i need? I basically want to display everyone regardless of whether they have an entry for today or not

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, the condition needs to go in the `ON` clause rather than the `WHERE` clause, because it is on the second table.

Second, `getdate()` -- despite its name -- has a time component.  So, convert it to a `date`:

```
FROM Person P LEFT JOIN
     Figure F
     ON P.id = F.id AND F.Date = CAST(getdate() as DATE)
```

Answer (score 0):

Put your query in a cte and then pull from it to achieve your desired results:

```
;with cte_example
as
(SELECT 
P.[Name], 
P.[id], 
F.[DATE], F.[Figure], F.[id]
FROM
Person P
LEFT JOIN Figure F
ON P.id = F.id)

select Name
       ,id
       ,cast(getdate() as date) as date
       ,case when date = convert(date, getdate()) then Figure else 0 end as Figure
from cte_example
```

I made a [rextester example](http://rextester.com/IZIUQ90181) so you could see